# Is it deeply inappropriate of using Nodejs+Express to build middleware layer in High-Concurrency architecture?

Tags: node.js, middleware

In my case, there is a large system wrote in Python need to rebuild, thoroughly, in less than one month. Node.js is the first thing I could think of to implement "Rapid Iteration".

Right now, I need to design a Middleware Layer to separate out all the database access through http request from Node.js.

My question is, if still using Node.js+Express to build the Middleware Layer, is it deeply inappropriate? If is, any suggestions? GoLang? Rust? or commercial middleware products?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you already use js/go/rust on the backend? If not then I don't see any reason to introduce new language. Besides you wouldn't ask such question if there were such reasons.

Comment: @Dan D. , one of the reasons of thinking so is, didn't see any "famous" or successful cases, and don't know whether is could be "Best Practice".

Comment: @freakish by now, the backend is clear

Comment: I'm not sure how does that answer my question. :D If you already use Python (and you don't use those mentioned languages) then stick with Python. It is highly unlikely that there is anything in js/go/rust that cannot be done in Python with similar scalability capabilities (if we are talking about complex enough application were bottleneck is almost always on database). But introducing new language will have negative impact on maintenance costs. Unless there is no language at all, i.e. this is your first language... but then I would stick with Python anyway. :D

Comment: @freakish , the old system was built by python, right now, I'm using Node.js to rebuild it.

Comment: @freakish , The bottleneck of old system is, it have no layers, everything massed together,  it's impossible to extract out thousands of hard-coded SQLs from the source code, that made the database very inefficient......Alright, I'm using Node.js to rebuild it, and trying separate out the Middleware Layer, not the inverted situation :D

Comment: You can do whatever you want. But if you wish to hear my advice then it is simple: the problem is not language. Stay with Python. You can do everything with it and it will be easier to maintain for your company (unless you're the only coder there). Do not introduce new language unless absolutely necessary (which is almost never).

Comment: @freakish it's really not about language

Answer (score 0):

Node.js, Python, Rust and Go are all very capable languages.

If you are already rebuilding the app in Node.js you should probably stick to that. If your main code base is in python, you should probably use python.

None of the languages you mentioned are "wrong" or "inappropriate".